# DAG first task to wait until all the tasks of previous DAG run is completed

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have the following tasks in DAG:

task 1 --> task 2 --> task 3 --> task 4 --> task 5

**I have the below configuration in my dag**

max_active_runs=1,default_args=default_values,catchup = False, schedule_interval=None

**Default values:**

default_values = {
"owner": "airflow",
"depends_on_past": True,
"start_date": datetime(2020, 4, 11),
"email_on_failure": True,
"email":[email],
"retries": 0
}

In the current run if suppose task 3 has failed ,the DAG is marked as Failed. When the next run is triggered how can I ensure that task 1 will not start until task 3 from previous run completes successfully.

I tried trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE in the task 1 but it dint help.

Thanks.!

Comment: With `max_active_runs=1`, two instances of the DAG cannot run at a time. Then Airflow is exhibiting the expected behaviour: only after current DagRun has been marked failed (or success), the next run is triggered. It is not as though the task from current DagRun is still `Running` or is `UpForRetry`, that the next `DagRun` starts. What more do you want? Do you want that if the current `DagRun` has failed, then next one shouldn't start? This is why this is not supported: it would mean that such a DAG can be run only as long as it succeeds. Once it fails, it could never be run again.